I do not understand difference between multi-cast delegates and events
I can achieve everything which event can achieve using multi-cast delegate.
you name it
Can anyone explain with an example
The only difference I can see is event keyword
The most common answer I heard is encapsulation ,loosely coupled etc. but I can do that with multicast delegate too

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/distinguish-delegates-events

Yes ,This is helpful,Thanks
